# How to display date in angular with filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

How to display date in angular with filter.

Below output shows the input and the output (with/without angular date filter)

```
In: {{v.Dt}}  
Angular: {{v.Dt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}
prints:

In: 2015-03-19T05:52:10.634062Z 
Angular: 2015-03-19T05:52:10.634062Z 

The desired display format is 19 Mar 2015
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had similar problem and then I came across this solution:

### Add this into your **app.js** file

```
angular.module('AngularAuthApp').filter('Convertdate', function ($filter) {
    return function (input) {
        if (input == null) { return ""; }
        var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd MMM yyyy');
        return _date.toUpperCase();
    };
});
```

### And then call like this

```
   <small class="styleColor">{{Event.EventStartDate | Convertdate}}</small>
```

EventStartDate is your datefield

You also can change the format of date in this

```
var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd MMM yyyy');
                                                 ^^ here
```

To mention that **angularauthapp** is your app name

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the markup

```
{{v.Dt | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}
```